# Angular 2 wrapping responsive horizontal gallery

Tags: css, angular, typescript, responsive, image-gallery

I'm trying to implement an horizontal gallery that wraps images based on their dimension.
The effect I would like to achieve is like this:

[image]

Is there any way to do this?

**EDIT**

I'll add something that I tried.

**1.** I've used [angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) with the *fxLayoutWrap* functionality. This wraps images correctly but I've not been able to create an horizontal scrolling gallery. Moreover the images dimension is a bit static and I need a dynamic wrapping:

```
<div fxFlex="80%" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap>
    <div fxFlex="30%" style="background:#ff0000">IMAGE 1</div>
    <div fxFlex="45%" style="background:#ff6a00">IMAGE 2</div>
    <div fxFlex="25%" style="background:#b200ff">IMAGE 3</div>
    <div fxFlex="33%" style="background:#ffd800">IMAGE 4</div>
    <div fxFlex="67%" style="background:#ff006e">IMAGE 5</div>
    <div fxFlex="50%" style="background:#808080">IMAGE 6</div>
    <div fxFlex style="background:#00ff90">IMAGE 7</div>
</div>
```

**2.** I tried to use custom *css* and *html*. In this case I'm able to build an horizontal scrolling gallery but I'm not able to wrap images dinamically and I have to set width and height manually.

*Html code:*

```
<div class="h-scroll-container">
    <div class="h-scroll">
        <div style="display:inline-block; width:15em; height:100%">
            <div class="thumb" style="background-image:url(images/project_1.jpg); width:100%; height:50%;"></div>
            <div class="thumb" style="background-image:url(images/project_2.jpg); width:100%; height:50%;"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="thumb" style="background-image:url(images/project_3.jpg); display:inline-block; width:15em; height:100%;"></div>

        <div style="display:inline-block; width:30em; height:100%;">
            <div style="width:100%; height:50%;">
                <div class="thumb" style="background-image:url(images/project_4.jpg); display:inline-block; width:50%; height:100%;"></div>
                <div class="thumb" style="background-image:url(images/project_5.jpg); display:inline-block; width:50%; height:100%;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="thumb" style="background-image:url(images/project_6.jpg); display:inline-block; width:100%; height:50%;"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="thumb" style="background-image:url(images/project_7.jpg); display:inline-block; width:15em; height:100%;"></div>

        <div style="display:inline-block; width:30em; height:100%">
            <div class="thumb" style="background-image:url(images/project_8.jpg); width:100%; height:50%;"></div>
            <div class="thumb" style="background-image:url(images/project_9.jpg); width:50%; height:50%;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS code*:

```
.h-scroll-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto!important;
    overflow-y: hidden!important;
}

.h-scroll {
    height: calc(100% - .5em);
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.thumb {
    background-position:center; 
    background-size:cover; 
}
```

**3.** I'm now trying to adapt [this](https://github.com/BenjaminBrandmeier/angular2-image-gallery) to my case. Here the code:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewChildren, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, SimpleChanges, QueryList, ChangeDetectorRef, OnChanges, AfterViewInit } from "@angular/core";
import { slideToLeft } from "../../router.animations";

var $: JQueryStatic = require('jquery');
import 'jquery-mousewheel';
require("jquery-mousewheel")($);
require('malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin')($);

export class Image {
    name: string;
    path: string;
    width: number;
    height: number;

    galleryImageLoaded: boolean;
    srcAfterFocus: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: "projects",
    template: require("./projects.component.html"),
    styles: [require("./projects.component.css")]
})
export class ProjectsComponent implements OnChanges, AfterViewInit {
    @Input('flexBorderSize') providedImageMargin: number = 10
    @Input('flexImageSize') providedImageSize: number = 10

    @ViewChild('galleryContainer') galleryContainer: ElementRef
    @ViewChildren('imageElement') imageElements: QueryList<any>

    @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) triggerCycle(event) {
        this.scaleGallery()
    }

    @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event']) windowResize(event) {
        this.render()
    }

    private images: Image[] = [];
    private gallery: any[] = [];

    constructor(private ChangeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.fetchDataAndRender()
    }

    public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        // input params changed
        this.render()
    }

    private fetchDataAndRender() {
    var images: Image[] = [
        {
            name: "project_1.jpg",
            path: "images/projects/project_1.jpg",
            width: 521,
            height: 375,
            galleryImageLoaded: false,
            srcAfterFocus: ''
        },
        {
            name: "project_2.jpg",
            path: "images/projects/project_2.jpg",
            width: 534,
            height: 375,
            galleryImageLoaded: false,
            srcAfterFocus: ''
        },
        {
            name: "project_3.jpg",
            path: "images/projects/project_3.jpg",
            width: 220,
            height: 375,
            galleryImageLoaded: false,
            srcAfterFocus: ''
        },
        {
            name: "project_4.jpg",
            path: "images/projects/project_4.jpg",
            width: 443,
            height: 375,
            galleryImageLoaded: false,
            srcAfterFocus: ''
        },
        {
            name: "project_5.jpg",
            path: "images/projects/project_5.jpg",
            width: 374,
            height: 375,
            galleryImageLoaded: false,
            srcAfterFocus: ''
        },
        {
            name: "project_6.jpg",
            path: "images/projects/project_6.jpg",
            width: 1052,
            height: 375,
            galleryImageLoaded: false,
            srcAfterFocus: ''
        },
        {
            name: "project_7.jpg",
            path: "images/projects/project_7.jpg",
            width: 235,
            height: 375,
            galleryImageLoaded: false,
            srcAfterFocus: ''
        },
        {
            name: "project_8.jpg",
            path: "images/projects/project_8.jpg",
            width: 570,
            height: 375,
            galleryImageLoaded: false,
            srcAfterFocus: ''
        },
        {
            name: "project_9.jpg",
            path: "images/projects/project_9.jpg",
            width: 328,
            height: 375,
            galleryImageLoaded: false,
            srcAfterFocus: ''
        },
        {
            name: "project_10.jpg",
            path: "images/projects/project_10.jpg",
            width: 521,
            height: 375,
            galleryImageLoaded: false,
            srcAfterFocus: ''
        },
        {
            name: "project_11.jpg",
            path: "images/projects/project_11.jpg",
            width: 534,
            height: 375,
            galleryImageLoaded: false,
            srcAfterFocus: ''
        },
        {
            name: "project_12.jpg",
            path: "images/projects/project_12.jpg",
            width: 220,
            height: 375,
            galleryImageLoaded: false,
            srcAfterFocus: ''
        },
        {
            name: "project_13.jpg",
            path: "images/projects/project_13.jpg",
            width: 235,
            height: 375,
            galleryImageLoaded: false,
            srcAfterFocus: ''
        },
        {
            name: "project_14.jpg",
            path: "images/projects/project_14.jpg",
            width: 570,
            height: 375,
            galleryImageLoaded: false,
            srcAfterFocus: ''
        },
    ]

    this.images = images;
    //this.ImageService.updateImages(this.images)

    // twice, single leads to different strange browser behaviour
    this.render();
    this.render();
}

private render() {
    this.gallery = []

    let tempRow = [this.images[0]]
    let rowIndex = 0
    let i = 0

    for (i; i < this.images.length; i++) {
        while (this.images[i + 1] && this.shouldAddCandidate(tempRow, this.images[i + 1])) {
            i++
        }
        if (this.images[i + 1]) {
            tempRow.pop()
        }
        this.gallery[rowIndex++] = tempRow

        tempRow = [this.images[i + 1]]
    }

    this.scaleGallery()
}

private shouldAddCandidate(imgRow: Image[], candidate: Image): boolean {
    let oldDifference = this.calcIdealHeight() - this.calcRowHeight(imgRow)
    imgRow.push(candidate)
    let newDifference = this.calcIdealHeight() - this.calcRowHeight(imgRow)

    return Math.abs(oldDifference) > Math.abs(newDifference) || (this.getGalleryWidth() + 1000) > this.calcOriginalRowWidth(imgRow)
}

private calcRowHeight(imgRow: Image[]) {
    let originalRowWidth = this.calcOriginalRowWidth(imgRow)

    let ratio = (this.getGalleryWidth() - (imgRow.length - 1) * this.calcImageMargin()) / originalRowWidth
    let rowHeight = imgRow[0].height * ratio

    return rowHeight
}

private calcImageMargin() {
    let galleryWidth = this.getGalleryWidth()
    let ratio = galleryWidth / 1920
    return Math.round(Math.max(1, this.providedImageMargin * ratio))
}

private calcOriginalRowWidth(imgRow: Image[]) {
    let originalRowWidth = 0
    imgRow.forEach((img) => {
        let individualRatio = this.calcIdealHeight() / img.height
        img.width = img.width * individualRatio
        img.height = this.calcIdealHeight()
        originalRowWidth += img.width
    })

    return originalRowWidth
}

private calcIdealHeight() {
    return this.getGalleryWidth() / (80 / this.providedImageSize) + 100
}

private getGalleryWidth() {
    if (this.galleryContainer.nativeElement.clientWidth === 0) {
        // IE11
        return this.galleryContainer.nativeElement.scrollWidth
    }
    return this.galleryContainer.nativeElement.clientWidth
}

private scaleGallery() {
    let imageCounter = 0
    let maximumGalleryImageHeight = 0

    this.gallery.forEach((imgRow: Image[]) => {
        let originalRowWidth = this.calcOriginalRowWidth(imgRow)

        if (imgRow !== this.gallery[this.gallery.length - 1]) {
            let ratio = (this.getGalleryWidth() - (imgRow.length - 1) * this.calcImageMargin()) / originalRowWidth

            imgRow.forEach((img) => {
                img.width = img.width * ratio
                img.height = img.height * ratio
                maximumGalleryImageHeight = Math.max(maximumGalleryImageHeight, img.height)
                this.checkForAsyncLoading(img, imageCounter++)
            })
        }
        else {
            imgRow.forEach((img) => {
                img.width = img.width
                img.height = img.height
                maximumGalleryImageHeight = Math.max(maximumGalleryImageHeight, img.height)
                this.checkForAsyncLoading(img, imageCounter++)
            })
        }
    })

    //if (maximumGalleryImageHeight > 375) {
    //    this.minimalQualityCategory = 'preview_xs'
    //} else {
    //    this.minimalQualityCategory = 'preview_xxs'
    //}

    this.ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
}

private checkForAsyncLoading(image: Image, imageCounter: number) {
    let imageElements = this.imageElements.toArray()

    if (image.galleryImageLoaded ||
        (imageElements.length > 0 && this.isScrolledIntoView(imageElements[imageCounter].nativeElement))) {
        image.galleryImageLoaded = true
        image.srcAfterFocus = image.path
    }
    else {
        image.srcAfterFocus = ''
    }
}

private isScrolledIntoView(element) {
    let elementTop = element.getBoundingClientRect().top
    let elementBottom = element.getBoundingClientRect().bottom

    return elementTop < window.innerHeight && elementBottom >= 0 && (elementBottom > 0 || elementTop > 0)
}
}
```

I've quite achieved my objective but I have to set manually the width check inside *shouldAddCandidate* method and rows are not of the same height. Some suggestions to make this more dynamic ad responsive?

Comment: That should help you get some answers.  I am not an expert on this, and not sure how to do it directly, but have you looked at something like Flexbox (the grid layout) to try to help?

Comment: Yes and it's not easy to realize what I'm looking for but I'm trying to adapt angular2-image-gallery pluging to my case, see the answer for details.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this?